# Setting up OpenSSH to use rhosts?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, networking, login

I rent a couple of VPSs running latest Ubuntu, both with OpenSSH.  I'd like to try password-less login using .rhosts/.shosts.  I know this is *not* recommended, and that it's better to use public-key authentication... I just want to *test* it and know how to set it up.  I want to log-in to my server/remote computer from my client/local computer without password.  I'm using a normal non-root user-account on my local computer, and wants to log-in to an account with the same user-name on the remote computer.

Here is a list of my questions:

- Must I list the local-computer's hostname and IP-address in /etc/hosts on the remote-computer?  Must I also list the hostname/IP of the remote-computer in /etc/hosts on the local-computer?  Does /etc/hosts matter in this at all?
- What's the difference between .rhosts and .shosts?
- As I understand it, the .rhosts/.shosts file goes in the user's home-directory on the remote-computer, and it must only be readable by the owner.  It should contain lines in the form "hostname  username"... Is this correct?
- Is it possible to drop username if it's the same on both computers, or *must* it be explicitly stated in .rhosts/.shosts?
- Is it possible to use this mechanism even if I got different username on the two computers (assuming the name I do have, is in .rhosts/.shosts)?
- Can I use IP-address instead of hostnames in .rhosts/.shosts?  Can I do it if /etc/hosts on the remote-computer includes this pairing?
- Which changes must I do to /etc/ssh/ssh_config and/or /etc/ssh/sshd_config, on both the remote and the local computer?
- Is it possible to optionally set it up so I avoid using the "global" /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts, and *just* use my local ~/.ssh/known_hosts?  Must this be set-up on the client/local, server/remote or both?
- Is it possible to optionally set it up to *ignore* the host-key(s) for the computer(s), i.e. just looking for .rhosts/.shosts and not authenticating the computer(s)?  (Yes I know this would be very stupid... I just want to know if it can be done.)
- Must I use the `rsh` or `rlogin` commands to get this to work, or will `ssh` also work - if the rest is set-up correctly?
- Is it somehow possible to test this mechanism "locally" - ie. on the same computer?  If I have several user-accounts on the same computer, could I add a .rhosts/.shosts file with entries for "localhost", "127.0.0.1" and/or my computers hostname - together with the username for my other account *on the same* computer - and get this mechanism to work?  After all, `ssh` can log-in to other accounts on "localhost" too...  If it's possible, how could I set it up?

Again, I'm just playing around and wanting to learn... I *know* it's not only unsafe, but also a case of crossing the stream to look for water.

Comment: I'm not sure that you chose a right format for your questions.  A very long list of questions tends to be left unanswered since people are responding on their own spare time and providing a detailed answer to each of your questions would take considerable time.  I'd suggest to ask your questions independently from each other, this way you will get answers faster.

Comment: follow steps mentioned in link http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_scp_without_password.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired functionality doesn't require setting up trust between two machines.  Also, this, as you properly mentioned, is not recommended from the security point of view.

What you likely want to do (if you want a password-less) login to the remote server is the following:

1. on your local machine under your user generate a passphrase-less key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and just pressing the **Enter** key on the password prompts.  This will generate a key without a passphrase.  So, if somebody steal the private key they would be able to access your server (unless you use a firewall to restrict access to the server to your IP address only)
2. copy the public key (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub if you didn't change the name of the key pair in the previous step) to your server to the home directory of the desired account.
3. under your desired account on the server create (if it's not there) the ~/.ssh directory with `mkdir -m700 -p ~/.ssh`
4. add the content of the public key you copied in step 2 to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (or if the file is not there, just rename the copied public key to that name)
5. ensure that the ownership and permissions on ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys are proper.  Both should be owned by the user of the home directory and their primary group, the ~/.ssh directory should have 0700 permission and ~/.ssh/authorized_key should have 0600 permissions.

From this point on connecting to the desired account from your local machine will be passwordless (you could use `ssh desired_user@remote.host` if you didn't change the name of the key pair, or use `ssh -i ~/.ssh/name_of_your_private_key desired_user@remote.host` if you changed the key name in step 1),

Now, if you still want to go the "totally insecure" way and establish trust between machines this is the HOWTO you are after: http://itg.chem.indiana.edu/inc/wiki/software/openssh/189.html -- I still do not recommend to go that route, unless you just want to see how it works.  Even in this case it is questionable since it's really a bad idea from the security standpoint.

Comment: Steps 2-5 can be replaced with simply running `ssh-copy-id user@remote-host` on the local machine that has both the public and private keys.  The remote host will ask for user's password this time only so a) user must have a password, and b) remote-host must be configured to allow password logins.  see the man page for `ssh-copy-id(1)` for more details.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but I prefer to explain how it works behind the scenes when I'm providing any advice.